# Trouble With Reading In A String With A Subroutine In LC3

Tags: string, subroutine, lc3

So I believe that the way I store the string works. I am just having some issues passing the String out of the subroutine. I heard that in order to pass something out of a subroutine you need to store it in R1 but I can't get it to store into my WORD array

```
   .orig   x3000
   AND     R1,R1,0
   LEA     R0,PROMPT
   PUTS

   JSR     GETS
   ST      R1,WORD

   LEA     R0,WORD
   PUTS

   halt

; ---------Data Area-------------
 WORD  .blkw   20   
 PROMPT .stringz "Enter String: " 
; -------------------------------      

GETS   LEA R1,MEMORYBLOCK ; saves the address of the storage memory block
loop   GETC               ; input character -> r0
   PUTC               ; r0 -> console
                      ; always points at the next available block

   LD      R2,EMPTY   ; check for 
   ADD     R2,R2,R0   ; end of line
   BRz     finish

   LD      R2,COUNTDOWN
   ADD     R2,R2,#-1
   BRz     finish
   ST      R2,COUNTDOWN

   STR     R0,R1,#0       ; r0 -> ( memory address stored in r1 + 0 )
   ADD     R1,R1,#1       ; increments the memory pointer so that it
   BR      loop

finish LEA      R1,MEMORYBLOCK
   RET


; ----Subroutine Data Area-------
 EMPTY       .fill   xfff6 
 COUNTDOWN   .fill   #10
 MEMORYBLOCK .BLKW   20
; -------------------------------

.end
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is the concept of "returning a string".  What you're actually doing at the end of GETS is returning the memory address at which the string starts.  When you then store this into WORD in the calling function, you are storing the memory address of the first byte of the string that was input (i.e. the memory address of MEMORYBLOCK) into the first byte of WORD.  You aren't copying the entire string from MEMORYBLOCK into WORD.

The easiest "fix" for what you're trying to do would be to change

```
   LEA     R0,WORD
```

to

```
   LD      R0,WORD
```

and then for good measure:

```
WORD  .blkw   20
```

to

```
WORD  .fill   0
```

as now you're just using it to store a single value (i.e. the memory address of MEMORYBLOCK).

However, at this point you haven't made a copy of the string.  If you want to do this, then you will need to make a loop whereby you walk through MEMORYBLOCK and copy each byte to WORD instead.

The final, cheaper, way to do this is to just use MEMORYBLOCK directly from the calling function.  It's not really any less valid in a program of this size, unless there's project requirements that ask otherwise.